# is that possible sql keep tracking the time?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm a freshman in sql. So that recently my lecture had give us one practical.
The practical file was showing an error.

```
INSERT INTO sales VALUES ('6380', '1111',     '2012-10-01 00:00:00', 2, '30',          'TC7777');
```

The error was `00:00:00`. As my lecture say SQL did not allow this format

So here comes my question:
- Is that possible SQL keep tracking all the time , like the 00:00:00 ?
- And is that SQL are key sensitive , SELECT and select or I should keep the habit that put all in upper case ?

Comment: what do you mean by key sensitive?Better to include your table schema in question

Comment: Select with SELECT , because I used to see my lecture wrote all AND , FROM , WHERE and ALTER NLS_DATE_FORMAT

Comment: Your question is unclear what you asking. Include your table structure, sample data, error information if any, and describe problem

Comment: sorry my bad , please give me a few moment to edit again

Comment: what us the table structure of your sales table

Comment: it contains book_id , book publisher data m publisher id and etc :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible SQL keep tracking all the time , like the 00:00:00 ?

If your Datatype in SQL table is `Date`, By default in Oracle, Default format for date is Date only so If you are specifying Time with date while inserting data you get error.

To Insert time with date, you have to convert date format while insert data

```
TO_DATE('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

[SEE Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/576f1f)

You can change this default date format with

```
alter session set nls_date_format= your date format here
```

[NLS_DATE_FORMAT Refer Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119)

> is that SQL are key sensitive , SELECT and select or I should keep the
>   habit that put all in upper case ?

SQL is not case sensitive, you can use either one, UPPER CASE, lower case or even Camel Case. Example :- `SELECT` or `select` or even `Select`. Just for better readability, Prefer to use All keywords in UPPER Case.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking to Oracle only, the database ALWAYS stores times with date/timestamp values.  You just have to properly tell it to do so.  In your example, you could say:

```
INSERT INTO sales 
VALUES ('6380', '1111', TO_DATE('2012-10-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')...
```

The default format for date values in Oracle is governed by the [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119) system parameter in the database.  If you don't explicitly supply date values with the TO_DATE function, Oracle will expect date strings to conform to this format.  That's why you're getting an error in your example.  Also, if you don't supply a time value, it defaults to 00:00:00.

The same principle applies on output, too.  You can accept the default output for a date value by simply selecting the value:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
27-JUN-15

SQL>
```

Or you can format it with TO_CHAR:

```
SQL> select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YY
-------------------
2015-06-27 11:10:48

SQL>
```

Comment: but , do I need to create a slot for the time ? In order to save the time ?

Comment: No. The DATE type stores a date and time in the same column/variable.